# How can i find LDAP server address?

Tags: c#

Im trying to figure out how to retrieve LDAP server adrdress in C#, there is a way on NSLOOKUP like:

```
C:\>nslookup _ldap._tcp.domain
Server:  rctr201.server.corp
Address:  10.10.10.10
```

Can you help-me please?

I tried to find some solution by topics here but i did not have a success :(

I will use the LDAP server to authenticate users on windows on my ASP.NET page.
If i put manually the correct LDAP Server on my code, its ok! Works but i need to find how get the LDAP Adress to make this automatic on code

Comment: You don't need to know the server address in order to validate users. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/13334508/62576

Comment: Man you are right! That's the solution i searching for, thanks, works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the IP address of a given host name, you can use the `System.Net.IPHostEntry` class. See the example below:

```
public string DnsLookup(string hostName)
        {      
            string ReturnedIPAddress ="";
            IPHostEntry ipHostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(hostName);            
            IPAddress[] ipAddress = ipHostEntry.AddressList;
            foreach (IPAddress ip in ipAddress)
            {
                ReturnedIPAddress += ip;
            }
            return ReturnedIPAddress;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks but i dont know the hostname the point is how to discover it like i did on "nslookup"